# Strange behavior Shift-Key Safari - HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, safari, dom-events

As requested, I simplified the problem as much as possible.

What I am trying to do is adding a `onmousemove` event to an HTML element, in this case the box, that will call a function. The problem I have is that not only mouse movements trigger the event, but also keys like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>... do.

So, once the mouse is passed over the box for the first time and the alert window is closed, any of the keys I mentioned previously will also make a new alert window pop up.

I am working with Safari, I also tested this on Google Chrome and the result is also a weird behavior of the browser.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"        "http://www.w3c.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            boxx = document.getElementById("box");
            boxx.onmousemove = showMessage;
        }


        function showMessage() {
            alert("hello");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>      
    <div id="box" style="width: 900px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I really don't understand what is happening, hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Post a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. Posting files elsewhere is of no use to others who may have the same issue and asking too much of those who may wish to help. The preparation of example code will often lead you to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: @RobG I made a completely different example much simpler out of it, the overall problem remains the same. Thanks for the advice, I hope this simplification encourages people to try it out.

Comment: I don't see the behaviour. Moving the cursor onto the div shows the alert, pressing enter dismisses it but it comes back because the cursor has moved since the the first alert was displayed so another mousemove event has been dispatched. Pressing enter dismisses the alert. Pressing any other key does not call the listener. Be very careful not to move the mouse so the cursor stays put. Note that a mousemove event will be fired about every pixel that the cursor moves, so there are a lot of them.

Comment: It may be best of you say what you are trying to do (e.g. drag and drop? hints?) so advice can be provided on how to deal with mousemove for your particular case.

Comment: Well, if I should be getting the alert message for every pixel I move the mouse, then it's just that the event does not work properly in my browser. Actually, I am able to fire the event without moving the mouse at all. If I place the file with the code on the desktop in a position such that when I double click on it and the new browser-window opens, the pointer of the mouse is already over the box, the event triggers automatically without any movements required. From that point, just pressing keys like SHIFT and CTRL will also show me the alert, that I can dismiss just pressing ENTER.

Comment: So, in all that process I haven't moved the mouse a single time, but I'm still getting the alert messages. Can it just be a problem with my browser (Safari 6.0.1)?